# Pandas: DataFrame.fillna but only from same day

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a sparse `DataFrame` and I want to `.fillna(method='ffill')`, *but only onto rows with the same date*?

For example, if `df` has rows:

```
2017-01-01 12:00   0.6
2017-01-01 13:00   NaN
2017-01-02 12:00   NaN
2017-01-02 13:00   0.8
```

Then I want to fill forward to produce:

```
2017-01-01 12:00   0.6
2017-01-01 13:00   0.6
2017-01-02 12:00   NaN
2017-01-02 13:00   0.8
```

Here's some code to create a sparse hourly DataFrame for demonstration:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(76), columns=list('X'), index=pd.date_range('2016-01-01', freq='H', periods=76))
df.loc[df['X'] < 0.6, 'X'] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perform a `groupby` on the day, then call `ffill`:

```
df = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='D')).ffill()
```

Comment: Do you know why `resample('D').ffill()` fails?

Comment: @ayhan: Do you mean `resample('H')`?  Wouldn't `resample('D')` downsample the hourly data down to daily, so it wouldn't really match?  From a couple tests, I think `resample('H')` only forward fills if there are hours that are missing entirely.  In this case all of the hours are there, some just happen to be null.  I think you'd need to drop the nulls first for it to work, something like `df['X'] = df['X'].dropna().resample('H').ffill()`.

Comment: I thought `ffill` would make it work like `groupby.transform` but you are right. Thank you.

Comment: Small note to avoid warning in later Pandas versions >= 0.24.0, TimeGrouper renamed to Grouper: `df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).ffill()`